# Insert records in sqlite database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I have a sqlite db and i want to insert row in it . I used this code .

```
 -(void)InsertRecords{

      NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"INSERT INTO notes (id, title, content,dataAdd,category) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\" ,\"%@\",\"%@\")",
                           @"1",
                           @"mountain",
                           @"Prahova",
                           @"12.09.2019",
                           @"public"];

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *updateStmt = nil;

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK){

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        NSLog(@"data inserted");

    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));

    }
    }
 else{
        NSLog(@"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
```

and it's log :  data inserted .

When i do this :

```
querySQL1 = @"select id from notes where category LIKE 'public'";
    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL1 UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

    NSString *idNr;
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        idNr =[[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:
                     (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

    }

    NSLog(@"%@",idNr);
```

idNr is null .

ANy ideea what is happening ? Any help will be appreciate . Thanks.

Comment: You must check the return value of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. If anything fails, log `sqlite3_errmsg` to see the error.

Comment: can you give an exemple how can i do this ? please

Comment: Do it just like you check if `sqlite3_open` worked or not. And do not use `stringWithFormat` to build queries.

Comment: what is your log? is it getting inserted?

Comment: no . if i log sqlite3_errmsg the mesage is that no table notes

Comment: @rmaddy i edit my question, please take a look

Comment: You're still not checking the result of `sqlite3_prepare_v2`. And you're still using `stringWithFormat:` to build your query. You state that an error says there is no "notes" table. You need to add the "notes" table to your database file before you can add rows to the table.

Comment: the table notes exist in db

Comment: @AdinaMarin If the `notes` table exists, why does your earlier comment show an error message claiming that the table doesn't exist? Can't be both. Perhaps your database path passed to `sqlite3_open` is wrong and you get a new empty database instead of the one you intended to open.

Comment: @rmaddy i update my question

Answer (score 0):

The NSString allocation was wrong statement, There were no need to alloc NSString object.

I changed :

```
NSString *idNr=@"";
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        idNr =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:
               (const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this snippet:

```
sqlite3 *database;
if (sqlite3_open(<#DBPath#>, &database)
    != SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_close(database);
    NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
    return nil;
}

char *update = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO <#Table name#> (<#key1#>,<#key2#>) VALUES (?,?);";
sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update, -1, &stmt, nil)
    == SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, <#the index#>,<#The text value#> , -1, NULL);
    sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, <#the index#>, <#the int value#>);
}
if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE){
    NSLog(@"Error inserting version in table <#tablename#>");
    return;
}
sqlite3_finalize(stmt);


sqlite3_close(database);
```

It uses the sqlite3_bind* functions to bind the values to the keys.

Comment: This code has many problems. Don't call `sqlite3_step` and `sqlite3_finalize` unless the call to `sqlite3_prepare_v2` succeeds. Don't return if `sqlite3_step` fails. You need to close the database even if `sqlite3_step` fails. And for anything that fails you should log `sqlite3_errmsg` so you know why it failed. And replace all of your `<#xxx#>` markup with realistic values based on the OP's question.

Comment: One other - why call `sqlite3_close` if `sqlite3_open` fails? That's pointless.